# Video/graphics card to support multiple types of cameras

Tags: windows, graphics-card, delphi

I'm not sure where to ask this question:)

I have a software in which a camera of **manufacturer SUMIX** is supported.
The software is in Delphi 6, and works well. The drivers are needed to view the camera image on the software.

Now the client wants the software to be able to support multiple cameras, and not just  **manufacturer SUMIX** but any camera that is suitable for the application.

Is this possible via a video/graphics card?
As in any  camera can be connected to the card and display the image on the software screen?

The camera is [smx-150m](http://www.sumix.com/products/cameras/smx-150m.html#TabbedPanels) also (en.ids-imaging.com/store/produkte/kameras/usb-2-0-kameras/ueye-le.html) and  will be USB because of the cost involved.

Is is possible using something like  [framegrabber](http://en.ids-imaging.com/store/produkte/framegrabber.html)
I mean to say if I connect the frame grabber to my system, I can connect any camera to the frame grabber and then display the image through the frame grabber on the software screen?

Comment: Which interface do those cameras have?

Comment: @AlexP. They are USB cameras

Comment: Why would you use a USB camera with a framegrabber?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams the current camera is USB, i wanted to know if frame grabber can support multiple cameras of different manufacturer. If its not USB also

Comment: Framegrabbers are meant to connect to "legacy" video connections such as composite; USB cameras... connect directly to the computer.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams oh ok,  so is it better to code the software to support a few cameras then use the frame grabber? what about graphic cards to connect a camera?

Answer (score 1):

If those cameras are USB-based, then your software can use `Windows Image Acquisition` (WIA) and/or `Windows Portable Devices` (WPD) API to talk to virtually any camera that identifies itself as such.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using DirectShow http://www.delphibasics.info/home/delphibasicsprojects/directxdelphiwebcamcaptureexample basically just a port of C++ PlayCap to Delphi, or here are some example of using WIA to get the images http://www.neunbeere.de/UseNet/WIA.html and https://gist.github.com/stijnsanders/1724324